# How to shift views up/down when UITable view show and hide in dropdown iOS

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I want to shift views up/down when UITable view show and hide in dropdown. Please check following views.

[image]

[image]

When I click on red button the table view opens and closes. But when it closes the space remains unused of table view. I want to shift below contents to the upward direction and vice versa. How to achieve this? If we could do it by storyboard autolayout then please let me know how to set constraints?

Below image constraint partially working -

[image]

Below image constraint  will not make any difference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set stack to your TableView and View. So, when you hide TableView it will automatically fill the space. Also, stack will help to to use less number of constraints to manage layout.